# Splice an Address

Tags: solidity, addresses, string

So in javascript I can take a string such as yourString[7] and get the 8th character within that string returned to me in string format. I want to take the last character in an Ethereum address, be an int or string and have that returned to me? Would I first convert it into the string, split that string into an array and then take the last element of that array?

Comment: `uint256(addr) % 16`

Comment: @goodvibration You should add the commend as an answer.

Comment: @Ismael: Can't because the question is unclear by definition. For example, it is not clear if this user wants to retrieve that last hex character as a string, a byte or a number.